# How to Plot 2 Lines on Log X-axis in Python?

Tags: python, plot, logarithm

I'm trying to plot blackbody wavelength vs flux for 288 Kelvin temperature (the Earth) and 6000 Kelvin temperature (the sun). I want both of these to be on the same plot and know I will need a log x-axis but I keep having issues having both lines appear. This is the code I have so far:

```
# Import libraries
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
c = 3.0e8 # m/s
h = 6.626e-34 # Js
k = 1.38e-23 # J/K

c1 = 2*np.pi*h*c**2
c2 = (h*c)/k

T1 = 6000
T2 = 288

lam = np.logspace(-8,-3,2000) # Generate x-axis values

F1 = c1/(lam**5*(np.exp(c2/(lam*T1))-1)) # Calculate y-values
F1 = F1/1e9

F2 = c1/(lam**5*(np.exp(c2/(lam*T2))-1)) # Calculate y-values
F2 = F2/1e9

# Create plot

ax = plt.gca()

plt.xlabel(r'$\lambda$ (nm)')
plt.ylabel(r'$F_{BB\lambda}(W\/m^{-2}nm^{-1})$')
plt.text(0.05,.8, 'T = {0:d}K'.format(T1), transform = ax.transAxes, size = 'small')
plt.text(0.05,.3, 'T = {0:d}K'.format(T2), transform = ax.transAxes, size = 'small')
plt.xticks(), plt.yticks()

plt.semilogx(lam*1e9, F1, lam*1e9, F2, color= 'black') # Create figure and axis objects
plt.xlim(10,1e6)
plt.ylim(0,)
plt.show() # Display plot to screen
```

This plots the attached picture which is correct for 6000K but for some reason it's not plotting the 288K curve and I'm not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: So you're getting a `RuntimeWarning`?

Comment: @Tyberius I just updated my post and defined T, F1, and F2 and I'm still not getting both lines on the plot

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I am running this through Jupyter Notebook and am not getting any warnings, just the plot that I attached. I updated the post with T, F1, and F2 defined

Comment: I'm also running Jupyter at your code results with a runtimewarning when calculating F2. An issue is in `(np.exp(c2/(lam*T2))-1)` which results in `inf` in the array.

Comment: @Sjcarlso this seems to not actually be a code issue. The flux for 288K is actually plotted, it's just orders of magnitude smaller than for 6000K, see here https://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss1/emfield/blackbody.php. This makes intuitive sense: the Earth is clearly radiating much less light than the Sun.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney When I separately compute F2 I get values `[0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 7.64803591e-09
 7.47495425e-09 7.30578339e-09]` so that must be why there's an error. I'm not sure how to fix this though since it works fine for 6000

Comment: @Tyberius Oh okay! Do you know how I could adjust the code so I can see both of the lines here?

Comment: It's just a warning, which numpy handles. You may have disabled warnings. I'm in JupyterLab.

Comment: Due to the difference in scale between the two, it will tough to see both. One thing you could do is have the y-axis be logarithmic as well. Alternatively, you could have a [zoomed inset plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html) to show the 288K, though at that point it may be easier just to have two plots.